# Linking outside Wordpress page on localserver

Tags: wordpress, linker, prestashop, permalinks, webshop

I've updated my website to a Wordpress site.
But now i have a problem with my prestashop, that i still need to be running on the server/webhost.
On my old page i had the prestashop installation called 'shop' inside my old site folder - so the link would be mysite.com/shop = worked fine.

I have nice permalinks working on my site, taking up all directions outsite WP sites as 'No result WP page' - And im stocked here..
I dont know where to put my prestashop folder or how to link to it from Wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set up the permailinks in Wordpress so your .htaccess looks like the following?;

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` is telling the server not to include rewrites for directories which are in the root of the install, so anything within your shop directory shouldn't be processed through `index.php`.

Comment: ups:
yes my htaccess looks like that.
So i should put the prestashop outsite my /www folder?

Comment: No, if you have your shop directory at the root of the WP install (ie alongside wp-content, wp-includes and wp-admin) then it should work, no?

Comment: McNab - Would you know why all img and styling linking suddently broke on my shop site?
I mean the page (html/php) loads, but not the rest - Was fine in the beginning, and have done changes?

Comment: Check what the paths are, permissions etc.  I've not used Prestashop to be honest, but I'd be looking at your global config setting for the domain and the shop .htaccess too?  At a guess.  Might be one for another question to be honest with you.